# Завершение дочернего процесса QProcess

Tags: c++, windows, unix, qt4

Как можно средствами Qt4 автоматически "убивать" запущенные дочерние процессы при падении основной программы? 
P.S. WinAPI использовать нельзя, потому что решение предполагается кроплатформенным.

Comment: все процессы Ваши или нет?

Comment: Нет, сторонние программы

Comment: Коллеги пытались решить - не выходит пока. Но у нас все программы свои и добавили просто локальный tcp сервер. Если сервер отвалился - все программы завершаются.

Comment: к сожалению у меня такая тема не прокатит((

Comment: Боюсь, что средствами Qt этого не добиться.

Comment: Мониторим наличие основной программы. Если она упала - убиваем те процессы что были для неё дочерними. В таком решении что-то не устраивает?

Comment: Вот и я видел такое решение - ещё одна программа - она знает, кого запустили и "правила игры". Если основная программа упала - она все позакрывает.